# Change the Laravel Login System in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm trying to determine if the user is allowed to login. Addiotional to the email with the correct password, I want to check if the user is active or not.

There is a active column in my database with the values "n" and "y". The login is supposed to fail if active == "n".

Now I'm trying to add this to the Login Controller but where ever I'm trying to put this if/else condition, it just gets ignored.

In the Laravel Doc. I found this:

Specifying Additional Conditions:

If you wish, you may also add extra conditions to the authentication query in addition to the user's e-mail and password. For example, we may verify that user is marked as "active":

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1 ( in my case "y"])) {
    // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
}
```

But this haven't workd for me.. Thats why I want to ask where do I have to put this code ( I've tried in the authenticatesUsers.php @login function ) and if I have to modify the code in a specific way? Laravel 5.5 is handling the login system a little bit different then 5.4 ( thats what I think at least )

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Your best way to do this is to add a method `login` to your `LoginController`

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'active' => 'y'])) {
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard'); 
    } else{
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Remember to add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` and `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` to the top of your controller.

Tested with `0` and `1`, and with `n` and `y` and it worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a method named 'attemptLogin' in your LoginController and add that code to the method as follows

```
   /**
 * Attempt to log the user into the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return bool
 */
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    return Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'active' => '1'], $request->filled('remember')
    );
}
```

This will override the method in the authenticatesusers trait while still utilising all the built in features of laravel authentication.

You must not forget to add this at the top of the page among your use directives

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

Then you are good to go.

Hope it helps someone